# Will a div with margins but no vertical padding collapse when empty?

Tags: css

I have a div which works to divide content up on my page. I need it to have horizontal padding and vertical margin to space out my content.

The problem is that the CMS puts this div on the page even when it doesn't have content. When this happens I need the div to behave as if it wasn't on the page and not add any spacing between the other divs which do have content.

When I tested this on my site it seemed like horizontal padding and vertical margin achieved this. However the demo below behaves differently:

```
div {
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m3xfspj8/

Comment: That link is a bit broken I think :)

Comment: I would imagine that the presence of the div would stop margin collapse, so you'd end up with a double margin space. If you can ensure that the div is completely empty i.e. <div></div> or <div /> without even whitespace in the Html, then you can use the :empty CSS psuedoclass to remove the margins.

Comment: You have dinamically add the padding(s) when you write something inside the DIV

Comment: @MarkRabjohn `<div />` is not an empty div, it's a start tag. With an error.

Comment: @Mr-Lister - of course back in my day we had XHTML - I still can't write <link> or <meta> tags without the self close syntax, not to mention <br>

Comment: @MarkRabjohn Back in my day we didn't have XHTML yet. So... I can look back and see it for the passing craze it was. Anyway, you know that for `<div />` to be a self-closing tag, the document needs to be served up as application/xhtml+xml, right? Also you don't need the space.